# How to bind 2 databse tables to gridview and one as dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="301px" AllowPaging="True" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentName" HeaderText="StudentName" SortExpression="StudentName" />
        <%--                    <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentDOB" HeaderText="StudentDOB" SortExpression="StudentDOB" />--%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DeptName">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#String.Format("~/Employee/EmployeeEditPage.aspx?StudentID={0}", Eval("StudentID"))%>'> Edit</asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">Delete</asp:LinkButton>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

above is my design:
below I wrote my code for to display the database, which have table `departmenttable` and another table `studenttable` to show the values into the grid. in department table I have `departmentname(dept_name)`
which should come in dropdown inside the gridview..but it showing error..pls help..

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DataBase.GetConnection());

    con.Open();
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
        {
            DropDownList ddList = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("dept_name");
            //bind dropdownlist
            DataTable dt = con.GetData("select dept_name from dbo.DepartmentTable");
            ddList.DataSource = dt;
            ddList.DataTextField = "dept_name";
            ddList.DataValueField = "DeptName";
            ddList.DataBind();

            DataRowView dr = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
            //ddList.SelectedItem.Text = dr["YourCOLName"].ToString();
            ddList.SelectedValue = dr["DeptName"].ToString();

            con.Close();
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What error is it showing? Please edit that into your question.

Comment: can you please update your question with error which you are facing ?

Answer (score 0):

For binding `dropdownlist` in `GriView` first you need to find it by its `id`. In your sample code, you are trying to find something which is not `dropdownlist`.
Try this,

```
DropDownList ddList = (e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList);

if(ddList != null)
{
    //your code
}
```

Comment: "GetData("select dept_name from dbo.DepartmentTable");"it showing error in GetData..

Comment: @dii - What error? You should post the actual error in your question!

Comment: @dii So, you have 2 problems ;) search for "c# getting data from sql server table"